# Fetching data from server(node.js) to client in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, axios

Basically, I want to fetch the stored data from mongodb atlas, using express and want to show it in react, I am able to fetch data from the mongodb but not able to send it to react from node, please help me

This is home.js which is a react file

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {
  
  const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState([]);
  const getHospitalsData = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/fetchdata/data')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        setHospitals(data);
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => getHospitalsData, []);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 className="text-center">Welcome to Nivaran</h2>
        
        {hospitals.map(hospital => {
          return <p>{ hospital } This</p>
        })}

      </div>
    );
  }


export default Home;
```

This is server.js(backend)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const routesUrls = require('./routes/routes');
const fetchData = require('./fetchData/fetchData');
// const home = require('./../src/components/homepage/home')

const cors = require('cors');

dotenv.config()

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_ACCESS, () => {
    console.log("db connected successfully..")
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/app', routesUrls)
app.use('/fetchdata',fetchData)

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running..")
})
```

This is fetchData.js

```js
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
// const http = require('http');

// var mydata = [];

const hospitalData = require('../modals/modal')
const cors = require('cors');
hospitalData.find({}, (err, data) => {
    // mydata = data
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log("This is the data we fetched for you:-", data)
    axios.post('/data', data);
});

// app.post('/data', mydata)

console.log("line from fetchData.js")

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

module.exports = router;
```

Error, I am getting

```js
(node:19184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag 
`--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:19184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Did your run your beck-end file server.js , before you trigger endpoint ?

Comment: yes absolutely I did

Comment: It seems you're fetch to wrong URL since your BE run on port 8000 and error message shows that you tried to fetch to port 80

Comment: Yes wrong url.. How do you open your react application? . You have to serve it using the `server.js`

Comment: Everything is there in the code, please tell me where I should make change